# Electron with selenium-webdriver: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, electron

In my Electron app, whenever I enter `npm run start` I receive the following error:

```
(node:3217) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: spawn /Users/christian/Code/drivers/chromedriver_mac_arm64/chromedriver ENOENT
    at /Users/christian/Code/MovieDork/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:260:24
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
(Use `Electron --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3217) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

The issue seems to have something to do with selenium-webdriver, where a rejected Promise was not caught. But I can't find out why this error is being thrown.

The goal of the program is to visit the Google search engine and use a Dork to find all video files containing a certain search term. Some of the code is incomplete but like I said, there seems to be an issue with selenium.

Here is my `main.js`:

```
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require("electron");
const squirrelStartup = require("electron-squirrel-startup");
const DownloadManager = require("electron-download-manager");
const exec = require("child_process").exec;
const path = require("path");
const os = require("os");

const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

const { Builder, Browser, By, Key, until } = require("selenium-webdriver");
const chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");

const maxResults = 30;

let driver;

if (squirrelStartup) {
  app.quit();
}

const customEnv = "development"; // production   development

// Create the browser window.
async function createWindow() {
  const servicePath =
    process.platform == "win32"
      ? path.join(__dirname, "../drivers/chromedriver.exe")
      : os.arch() == "x64"
      ? path.join(__dirname, "../drivers/chromedriver_mac64/chromedriver")
      : path.join(__dirname, "../drivers/chromedriver_mac_arm64/chromedriver");
  const service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder(servicePath);
  let options = new chrome.Options();
  if (customEnv === "production") options.addArguments("--headless");
  driver = await new Builder()
    .forBrowser(Browser.CHROME)
    .setChromeService(service)
    .setChromeOptions(options)
    .build();

  await driver.get("https://www.google.com/ncr");
  driver
    .findElement(By.id("L2AGLb"))
    .then((element) => {
      element.click();
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });

  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 900,
    height: 600,
    resizable: true,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "electron/guiExample.js"),
      contextIsolation: true,
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });

  // Load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "electron/guiExample.html"));

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app
  .whenReady()
  .then(() => {
    createWindow();

    app.on("activate", function () {
      // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
      // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
      if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
    });
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
  });

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on("window-all-closed", async function () {
  await driver.quit();
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") app.quit();
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
ipcMain.on("execute", (command) => {
  child = exec("ls", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log("exec error: " + error);
    }
  });
});

const getMovieFileFromWebsiteUrl = async (wUrl, movie_name) => {
  const extensions = [".mp4", ".mkv"];
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(wUrl);
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);

    const videoTags = $("video");
    const aTags = $("a");

    videoSources = [];

    aTags.each((index, element) => {
      let sourceUrl = $(element).attr("href");
      if (sourceUrl) {
        if (
          sourceUrl.indexOf(".mp4") != -1 ||
          sourceUrl.indexOf(".mkv") != -1
        ) {
          if (sourceUrl.charAt(0) == "/") sourceUrl = sourceUrl.substring(1);
          if (getDomainName(sourceUrl) == "") sourceUrl = wUrl + sourceUrl;
          let fname = "";
          let splitLink = sourceUrl.split("/");
          if (splitLink.length) {
            fname = splitLink[splitLink.length - 1];
          }
          videoSources.push({
            sourceUrl,
            fname,
          });
          // console.log(fname, movie_name);
          // if (fname.toLowerCase().indexOf(movie_name.toLowerCase()) != -1){
          // }
        }
      }
    });

    videoTags.each((index, element) => {
      let sourceUrl = $(element).attr("src");
      if (!sourceUrl) {
        if ($(element).find("source").attr("src"))
          sourceUrl = $(element).find("source").attr("src");
        else sourceUrl = "";
      }
      let fname = "";
      let splitLink = sourceUrl.split("/");
      if (splitLink.length) {
        fname = splitLink[splitLink.length - 1];
      }
      videoSources.push({
        sourceUrl,
        fname,
      });
      // console.log(fname, movie_name);
      // if (fname.toLowerCase().indexOf(movie_name.toLowerCase()) != -1){
      // }
    });

    return videoSources;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return [];
  }
};

function getDomainName(url) {
  var domain = "";

  if (
    url.indexOf("http") != -1 ||
    url.indexOf("https") != -1 ||
    url.indexOf("ftp") != -1
  ) {
    // find & remove protocol (http, ftp, etc.) and get domain
    if (url.indexOf("://") > -1) {
      domain = url.split("/")[2];
    } else {
      domain = url.split("/")[0];
    }
    // remove port number if there is one
    domain = domain.split(":")[0];
  }
  return domain;
}

async function getStackResult(pageSource, movie_name) {
  let stackRes = [];
  let $ = cheerio.load(pageSource);
  let urlLists = [];
  $("#rso")
    .find("a")
    .each(async (index, aTag) => {
      let wUrl = $(aTag).attr("href");
      let domain = getDomainName(wUrl);
      if (domain && domain.indexOf("google.com") == -1) {
        if (wUrl.charAt(wUrl.length - 1) != "/") wUrl += "/";
        urlLists.push(wUrl);
      }
    });

  for (let eUrl of urlLists) {
    const mlists = await getMovieFileFromWebsiteUrl(eUrl, movie_name);
    if (mlists.length) {
      mlists.map((mlist) => {
        let fres = stackRes.filter((ers) => ers.sourceUrl == mlist.sourceUrl);
        if (!fres.length) {
          stackRes.push(mlist);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  return stackRes;
}

ipcMain.handle("send_search_query", async (event, movie_name) => {
  //Test
  let lastRes = [];
  try {
    await driver.get("https://www.google.com/ncr");

    for (let pageNum = 1; pageNum <= 5; pageNum++) {
      if (pageNum == 1) {
        await driver
          .findElement(By.name("q"))
          .sendKeys(
            `-inurl:htm -inurl:html intitle:"index of" (avi|mp4|mkv) "${movie_name}"`,
            Key.RETURN
          );
        await driver.wait(
          until.titleIs(
            `-inurl:htm -inurl:html intitle:"index of" (avi|mp4|mkv) "${movie_name}" - Google Search`
          ),
          4000
        );
      } else {
        if (!driver.findElement(By.id("pnnext"))) break;
        await driver.findElement(By.id("pnnext")).click();
        await driver.wait(
          until.titleIs(
            `-inurl:htm -inurl:html intitle:"index of" (avi|mp4|mkv) "${movie_name}" - Google Search`
          ),
          4000
        );
      }

      let pSource = await driver.getPageSource();
      const pageRes = await getStackResult(pSource, movie_name);
      lastRes = [...lastRes, ...pageRes];
      if (lastRes.length >= maxResults) break;
    }

    await driver.get("https://www.google.com/ncr");

    return {
      status: "success",
      data: lastRes,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    await driver.get("https://www.google.com/ncr");
    return {
      status: "success",
      data: lastRes,
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: This error usually is related to a promise that is throwing error but not handled properly. I saw you call `driver.findElement(By.id("L2AGLb"))` and handle the error by `.catch`, but my guess is that maybe you should user `await` before this call since it does return a promise

Comment: @LuizFernandodaSilva thanks for the help, but this did not fix it. I changed the code to 
` 
const el = await driver.findElement(By.id("L2AGLb"));
 el.click();
` 
but I'm still getting the same error.